# in-app email makes swoosh sound but doesn't send

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I get to the Mail program fine, and when I press "Send" I hear the swoosh sound and Mail closes and returns me to my app, but the actual mail isn't sending.

Here's the code I'm using to mail.  Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

(I'm using iOS6, on an actual device, not the simulator.)

```
-(void)openMail {

            //Open Mail program and create email with haiku attached as image.

if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"subject"]];
    UIImage *myImage = [self createImage];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"xxxxx"];
    NSString *emailBody = @"I thought you might like this haiku from the xxxxx iPhone app.";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

            //Unless it's not possible to do so, in which case show an alert message.

else
{
    self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"I'm sorry." message:@"Your device doesn't seem to be able to email this haiku. Perhaps you'd like to tweet it or post it on Facebook instead?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [self.alert show];
}
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this through the simulator?

Comment: Are you testing this in the simulator or on the device?  You'll need to do it on a device for a mail to actually send

Comment: How do you know that the email it not being sent?  Are you watching the packets with something like WireShark?

Comment: Make sure you are sending to the right Email Address.

Comment: I pretty sure if he doesn't get the file then the Email didn't got sent.

Comment: I'm sending to my own email address, and it's not arriving.

Comment: Do you have your email address setup on your device? If your mail app is not setup then it will not send.

Comment: Just to test, comment out the attachment code. Just try sending a simple email. Also, check your outbox in the actual Mail app. See if the email is stuck. BTW - the above code does not run the Mail app at all. You are not returned to your app since you never leave your app.

Comment: @iProgrammed: «I pretty sure if he doesn't get the file then the Email didn't got sent.» There's a fair number of things that can happen _after_ sending to make an email not arrive as intended. Also, please don't leave "See my answer" comments -- the question asker is notified instantly when your answer has been posted.

Comment: What is the MFMailComposeResult in the delegate response?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's actually a problem between my server and the iOS 6.1 update.  I'll leave this up in case other people have the same problem.  If the issue is fixed and my email STILL won't send, then I'll post another question.

Comment: Did you quit your app and open Mail on your device? It sounds like from the docs, that it doesn't actually send until you do that.